# Move DataSet from a form to the project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dataset, projects-and-solutions

I have a form with some ToolStrips, MenuStrips and a DataSet on it.

Lately I added another form and I need the DataSet to be available here also. Is there any way to move the DataSet from form controls to the project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another DataSet inside the project hierarchy because I didn't find any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the DataSet object from one form to the other. You can use the constructor of the second form to do this. Or the second form can have a pubic method or property using which the DataSet object can be passed.

Comment: I know I can do this, but is there another way? Or I will be forced to create a DataSet inside the project?